# Why Port automatically closing on Google cloud?

Tags: node.js, networking, google-cloud-platform, vps

Hey everyone I am trying to deploy a simple node is chat app with web sockets on Google Cloud Platform in firewall I opened Port 3000 and I am testing it. It works fine for some time but after some when I go to that Port directly it says connection refused see screenshot I attached
[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdAYR.jpg)

Comment: This may be related to the nature of your application.  You didn't say where you were running the Node.JS app?  Is it a Compute Engine, Kubernetes, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, App Engine or something else?

Comment: if ur running an instance of node and want to persist the node server, try using nodemon and pm2

Comment: Do you use a load balancer?

Comment: Can you get to the localhost:3000 on your instance?